# When is a thread actually terminated when calling TerminateThread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

If I terminate a thread on Windows using the [`TerminateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, is that thread actually terminated once the function returns or is termination asychnronous?

Comment: [In fact, there is no justification to using TerminateThread. It is only safe to use when you control exactly what that thread is doing (e.g. you know that it doesn’t do heap allocation, and it is not inside a critical section). But if you are the programmer of that thread’s function, then why not write code that returns safely from the thread function upon some event or flag, or calls ExitThread when needed?](http://adilevin.wordpress.com/tag/terminatethread/)

Comment: I fact, I am aware of the implications that `TerminateThread` has, but I am nevertheless interested when the execution of the code stops, because the documentation does not answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define "actually terminated". The documentation says the thread can not execute any more user-mode code, so effectively: yes, it is terminated, nothing of your code is going to be executed by that thread any more.

If you "WaitForSingleObject" on it right after terminating, I guess there could still be some slight delay because of cleanup that Windows is doing.

By the way: TerminateThread is the worst way of ending a thread. Try using some other means of synchronization, like a global variable that tells the thread to stop, or an event for example.

Comment: That was what I meant: no code from the function that was passed to `CreateThread` will be executed once `TerminateThread` returns.

Answer (score 3):

Terminating a thread is akin to killing a process, only on a per-thread level. It may in fact be implemented by raising an (uncatchable) signal in the targeted thread.

The result is essentially the same: Your program is not in any particular, predictable state. There's not much you can do with the dead thread. The control flow of your program becomes generally indeterminate, and thus it is extremely hard to reason about your program's behaviour in the presence of thread termination.

Basically, unless your thread is doing something extremely narrow, specific and restricted (e.g. increment an atomic counter once every second), there's no good model for the need to terminate a thread, and for the state of the program after the thread termination.

Don't do it. Design your threads so that you can communicate with them and so that their entry functions can return. Design your program so that you can always join all threads eventually and account for everything.

Comment: Well, it was OK until the last paragraph, but then I guess we're always going to disagree on that point <g>

Answer (score 0):

It is a synchronous call.  That does not mean that it necessarily returns quickly - there may be some blocking involved if the OS has to resort to using its inter-core driver to stop the thread, (ie. it's actually running on a different core than the thread requesting the termination).

There are issues with calling TerminateThread from user code during an app run, (as distinct from the kernel using it during app/process termination), as clearly posted by others.

I try very hard to never terminate threads at all during an app run, with TerminateThread or by any other means.  App-lifetime threads and thread pools often do not require any explicit termination before the OS destroys them on app close.